# How to reference dependency as file in Gradle?

Tags: database, gradle, dependencies

In Gradle, I would like to:

1. Specify a database file (e.g. .mdf file) as a dependency.

2. Attach that file to database instance.

I know how to do #2, using file path.

I don't know how to get file path of a downloaded dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577929/cleanest-way-in-gradle-to-get-the-path-to-a-jar-file-in-the-gradle-dependency-ca) question - it's quite self explanatory. However I suppose that better idea might be keeping the `mdf` file under `src/main/resources`. Why don't You put it there?

Comment: Storing large binary file in Git does not sound like a good idea.

Comment: In Git particularly or in general? Why not?